# Both HttpWebRequest and HtmlAgilityPack are unable to get text from table

Tags: vb.net, encoding, character-encoding, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

This is the original function I wrote to get the Html of a web page and parse it with the same code used for "IE.document"

The code works fine with some websites but now I get an error on "doc.write" and i think it's because the webpage has "iso-8859-1" encoding and a different encoding in the second column of the table I'm trying to parse.

```
Function mWebRe(ByVal mUrl As String) As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(mUrl)
    request.Timeout = 10000
    Dim doc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Try
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        'this is the original code
        'Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        'this is an attempt without effects
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")) 
        Dim WebContent As String = reader.ReadToEnd() 'Here the text seems to be
        doc.clear()
        doc.write(WebContent) 'Here I get error on loading page 
        doc.close()

        ' The following is a must do, to make sure that the data is fully load.
        While (doc.readyState <> "complete")
            Thread.Sleep(50)
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
    Return doc
End Function
```

I've tryed to modify the code and also tryed to use HtmlAgilityPack (I've never used it before) without success.

I need the content of the second "Table" (doesn't have id), so I wrote the code below (It isn't able to get the correct innertext from cells):

```
    Dim web As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb()
    web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
    Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = web.Load(mUrl)

    For Each Table As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table") 
        For Each Row As HtmlNode In Table.SelectNodes("//tr")
            For Each Cell As HtmlNode In Row.SelectNodes("//td")
                Dim mTxt As String = Cell.InnerText
            Next

        Next
    Next
```

This is the "start" of the webpage sourcecode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This is an extract of a row I would extract:

```
<tr>
<td class="tableValues" align="center" valign="top" >Mar 24/12/2013</td>
<td class="tableValues" align="left" valign="top" >&#73;sc&#114;it&#116;&#111; &#97;&#108; &#82;u&#111;&#108;<!--span-->&#111;<!--i>&#52;</i--></td>
<td class="tableValues" align="left" valign="top" ></td>
</tr>
```

I think that the second column has a different encoding but I don't have any idea on how to convert it to the correct text.
Any suggest is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved inserting the code below in the code with htmlAgilityPack.
But if anyone can suggest a better solution I'll be grateful.

```
            For Each Cell As HtmlNode In Row.SelectNodes("//td")
                Dim mTxt As String = Cell.InnerText
                If mTxt.Contains("&#") Then
                    Dim StrOk As String = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(mTxt)
                    StrOk = Regex.Replace(StrOk, "<!--.+?-->", String.Empty)
                    Debug.Print(StrOk)
                End If
```